# psutil - "System Idle Process" CPU percentage usage is over 100%

Tags: python, cpu-usage, psutil

So I am trying to print every task's CPU percentage and memory percentage and it looks great but for some reason  `"System Idle Process"` shows me above 100 CPU percentage e.g(312,201) in task manager it [looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3yrK.png), e.g(89%, 93%) not over 100 why is this happening

this is the code that I am using to get the percentage of each task:

```
running_programs = []
        for running_program in psutil.process_iter():
            infoDict = running_program.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'cpu_percent', 'memory_percent'])
            running_programs.append(infoDict)
        print(running_programs)
```

and [this is the output of the name `"System Idle Process"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9luR.png)

Comment: Unable to replicate on my machine. What version of psutil do you have? Try updating https://pypi.org/project/psutil/

Comment: @DillonMiller it prints that it's already satisfied

Comment: `pip install psutil -U`

Comment: @DillonMiller `Requirement already up-to-date: psutil in` `c:\users\pach\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (5.7.0)`

Comment: @DillonMiller So what do you suggest doing?

Answer (score 0):

Percentage values greater than 100 can occur on processes that take advantage of multithreading. Psutil's Documentation:

"Note the returned value can be > 100.0 in case of a process running multiple threads on different CPU cores."

To fix this you can use:

```
process.cpu_percent() / psutil.cpu_count()
```